# Spring Data JPA repository find method returns null collection but collection size is correct

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

with Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.3.8.Final.

When I query using `findAll`, the collection returns contains `null` values **but the size of the collection is correct**.

Relevant snippet:

```
public interface UnitRepository extends JpaRepository<Unit, Integer> {

    @Transactional
    @Query("SELECT t FROM Unit t WHERE t.clientNo = ?1")
    public List<Unit> findByUnitNo(String clientNo);
```

[image]

What to do?

Comment: Could you post your spring configuration?

Comment: posted the updated one

Comment: Issue resolved, it required an @ID for the POJO.class.

Comment: @Mukti You can then answer your own question and approve it.